# Why this array is bugging? I used simple event target toggle to add and remove element

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

```
This html should look like in table each number is in cell
```

```
Each number is clickable to add it in array and can be toggle to remove in array
```

```
The problem here is it bugg when number is toggle to remove in array, the array element becomes incorrect
```

```
Some element went missing in the ARRAY when toggle only one number to remove
```

```
 Sometime all elements are missing in the ARRAY when only 1 element toggled to remove
```

```
<div class="board x" id="board">
                <button class="btn-nmbers" id="btn" value="1" data-cell>1</button>
                <button class="btn-nmbers" id="btn" value="2" data-cell>2</button>
                <button class="btn-nmbers" id="btn" value="3" data-cell>3</button>
                <button class="btn-nmbers" id="btn" value="4" data-cell>4</button>
                <button class="btn-nmbers" id="btn" value="5" data-cell>5</button>
                <button class="btn-nmbers" id="btn" value="6" data-cell>6</button>
                <button class="btn-nmbers" id="btn" value="7" data-cell>7</button>
                <button class="btn-nmbers" id="btn" value="8" data-cell>8</button>
                <button class="btn-nmbers" id="btn" value="9" data-cell>9</button>
                <button class="btn-nmbers" id="btn" value="10" data-cell>10</button>
                <button class="btn-nmbers" id="btn" value="11" data-cell>11</button>
                <button class="btn-nmbers" id="btn" value="12" data-cell>12</button>
                <button class="btn-nmbers" id="btn" value="13" data-cell>13</button>
                <button class="btn-nmbers" id="btn" value="14" data-cell>14</button>
                <button class="btn-nmbers" id="btn" value="15" data-cell>15</button>
                <button class="btn-nmbers" id="btn" value="16" data-cell>16</button>
                
                

            </div>
        </div>
```

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16|

```
const cellNumbers = document.querySelectorAll('[data-cell]');
const board = document.getElementById('board')


const selectedNumbers = [];

clickCell()
//Make the all cell clickable/toggle
function clickCell (){
    cellNumbers.forEach(item => { 
        item.addEventListener("click", cellValue)
    });
}

//Get the value in each cell
function cellValue(event){
    const cell = event.target.value;
    cell.cellNumbers;
    
    if(event.target.cell === cell.cellNumbers){
        event.target.classList.toggle('x');

        addRemoveToArray(selectedNumbers, cell);
        
    }
    console.log(selectedNumbers)
}

function addRemoveToArray (arr, val){
    const idx = arr.indexOf(val);
    //console.log(idx)

    idx === -1 ? arr.push(val) : arr.splice(idx, val);
}
```

Comment: Can you please create a [mre] of your issue so that we can help debug it ourselves?

Comment: Please include your HTML too.

Comment: added some notes to elaborate the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't 100% sure what your script was intended to do, but I came up with this which might help get you on the right track:

```js
const cellDivs = document.querySelectorAll('[data-cell]');
const selectedNumbers = [];

cellDivs.forEach(cellDiv => cellDiv.addEventListener("click", updateState));

function updateState(event){
  event.target.classList.toggle('selected');
  toggleInArray(selectedNumbers, event.target.dataset.cell);
}

function toggleInArray(array, value){
  if(array.indexOf(value) === -1){
    array.push(value);
  }else{
    array.splice(array.indexOf(value), 1); // Splices 1 element out
  }
  console.log(array);
}
```

```css
#board{ display: flex; }
[data-cell]{ padding: 0.4em 0.6em; border: 1px solid grey; }
.selected{ background: lightskyblue; }
```

```html
<div id="board">
  <div data-cell="1"> 1 </div>
  <div data-cell="2"> 2 </div>
  <div data-cell="3"> 3 </div>
  <div data-cell="4"> 4 </div>
  <div data-cell="5"> 5 </div>
  <div data-cell="6"> 6 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code works perfect what I wanted. Mine was whenever i clicked the added number the other number went missing also, anyway great job! Ill analyze this thanks!